# Detect when none of app windows is active/focused

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

How detect when user changes focus from multi-window application (alt+tab e.g.).

I want to detect when none of the app windows is active/focused.

First window is always shown but user can work with up to four windows(none of these is shown as dialog).

Comment: @Hank I want to know how to determine whether user left any window; Deactivated event applies to single window, how could I check if user switched from 1st to 2nd windows or from 1st to other application?

Comment: @Iluvatar Please update the OP with your exact request and a description of the situation in which you wish to use it. That way we can accurately advise on how to approach it.

Comment: When do you want to be informed? Are you looking for an event or just want to check it in some part of code to see if any of forms are active? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @RezaAghaei This app is connected to server. I want this client app to send signal if app is not used(but still running) by user

Comment: Just send message across on activate event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form` has a [`ContainsFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.containsfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) property that indicates whether the form, or one of its child controls has the input focus. You can check this property for all open forms to detect if the application contains focus or not:

```
var isActive = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Any(x=>x.ContainsFocus);
```

Also as another option:

```
var isActive = (Form.ActiveForm != null)
```

If you want to be notified of the state of the application you can handle `Activate` and `Deactivate` event of your forms for all forms.

```
private void f_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (Form.ActiveForm == null)
            Text = "App Deactivated.";
        else
            Text = "Still Active";
    }));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't mean that application or user isn't idle. It just shows you if the application contains focus.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you @RezaAghaei

Comment: Great! You're welcome :)